# how remove all character unicode

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode-escapes

I need to create a .csv but there are some column that not are display correct.

```
a b  c -----> column
cc; dsf -->value
```

I need to delete characted uncode from a string that the user can insert in db.

My code is

```
 translate(column, chr(10)||chr(11)||chr(13)||CHR(09), ' ')
```

I think there are other character that can gives problem to my .csv

anyone can help me?

Comment: Please update your source data to format it as a table, so it is possible to tell which values should appear in which columns. What are the field delimiters and row delimiters in your file?

Comment: *there are other character that can gives problem to my .csv* - if you know that, then you need to describe them in some way. Otherwise it's pretty impossible to fix abstract things